# Git Bash - Git is showing branches as being up to date when they actually aren't

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I've got two local branches, *main* and *dev*. When I try commiting and pushing changes from dev to main, it says everything is up to date and nothing actually happens. Additionally, my github repo does not reflect the latest changes in my local repo, even though I have tried pushing it up and it says it was successful. Commits are not showing on my new repo.

When I type "git remote show origin", this is the output:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: <myRepo'sURL>
  Push  URL: <myRepo'sURL>
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branches:
    dev  tracked
    main tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    main merges with remote main
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev  pushes to dev  (fast-forwardable)
    main pushes to main (up to date)
```

I'm very new to git so sort of learning as I go. Anybody have any idea as to why I am experiencing this issue? I can run other commands to provide more info if needed

To push changes, here is the process I follow:

First, git status. The output is this:

```
On branch dev
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   __pycache__/app.cpython-39.pyc
        modified:   app.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then, I run "git add ." No output from this command.

Next, "git commit -m "test". Here is the output:

```
$ git commit -m "test"
[dev 5af52ce] test
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

Finally, "git push origin main". Here is the output:

```
$ git push origin dev
Enumerating objects: 20, done.
Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 1.77 KiB | 1.77 MiB/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (10/10), completed with 3 local objects.
To <myRepo'sURL>
   0f1504d..5af52ce  dev -> dev
```

Thanks!

Comment: We need more detail. What do you mean by "I try commiting and pushing changes"? What exact commands do you do? What are the results of these commands? You can check that each commit contains the changes you expect using commands like `git status`, `git log`, and `git diff`. Use `git help <command>` for more details about how to use these commands.

Comment: Based on the output shown here, the command `git push origin dev` would probably send new commits that you have on your `dev`, that do not exist yet on the Git repository over at GitHub, to the Git repository over at GitHub. (It's possible that your `dev` is even with your `main` and the GitHub `dev` is simply behind; we can't tell from what you've shown here.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've just added some more info. After checking github just now it seems that I can push straight from my local dev branch to the dev branch on github, bypassing the "main" branch entirely. I'm guessing my branch hierarchy is screwed up, but i'm not sure how to check/fix that

Comment: "bypassing the main branch entirely", but this is how git works... Perhaps this is just some confusion about how git actually works? Can you elaborate about what the problem actually is here? What I mean by this is that you probably see some status message that you disagree with, can you post that **exact** status message (or other observation), explain why you disagree and what you expected it to show?`So far all the commands and output in your question seems to indicate that there isn't a problem, but clearly you have one since you have asked a question.

Comment: I suspect part of the confusion here is from what you see on GitHub. By default, GitHub will show the directory structure of the `main` branch. You can select the `dev` branch to see its contents. You can also set the default branch to whatever branch you wish.

Comment: You say "Finally, "git push origin main". Here is the output:", but the output is from `git push origin dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try commiting and pushing changes from dev to main,

What you are doing is pushing from `dev` to `origin/dev`.
And since the remote repository display the default branch `main`, you don't "see" any obvious changes (you would need to switch to the dev branch in the web page in order to see your commit).

You can merge dev locally to main, then push main:

```
git switch main
git merge dev
git push
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, I just mixed up on commands/terminology and "merge" was what I needed. Thank you!